# hashed password being stored as NULL :Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to store a password after hashing it but it shows up as NULL in the database.I generated a  scaffold for users using password string and name string, and then altered the mysql table to store hashed password instead using this :

```
ALTER TABLE users CHANGE password hashed_password CHAR(40) NULL;
```

my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password
  attr_accessible :name, :password

  validates :name, :uniqueness => true
  validates :password, :length => { :in => 6..20 }

  def before_create
    self.hashed_password = User.hash_password(self.password)
  end

  def after_create
    @password = nil
  end

  private

  def self.hash_password(password)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(password)
  end

end
```

I am using Rails 3.2.13.

Comment: What are you using to see that the stored hashed password is null?

Comment: i am using mysql prompt

Comment: open rails console and try this

u = User.create(name: 'XYZ', password: 'password123')
u.errors
and check the errors

Comment: => #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00000003a851a8 @base=#<User id: 5, name: "Xaaa", hashed_password: nil, created_at: "2013-06-03 07:26:58", updated_at: "2013-06-03 07:26:58">, @messages={}>
No errors it seems.

Comment: I think it putting the password in db instead of hashed one ..but I cant understand the reason.

Comment: Looks like it should work. Are you sure that you are editing the file that's actually being used? Are other changes to that file taking effect?

Comment: I am restarting server after saving models...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
 before_create :hash_the_password
 after_create :nil_the_password

 def hash_the_password
    self.hashed_password = User.hash_password(self.password)
 end

 def nil_the_password 
    @password = nil
 end
```

and NOT

```
 #Wrong?
 def before_create
    ...
 end
```

so the callbacks can be the problem.

Comment: What about @hashed_password = ... (@password) 
instead of self.hashed_password ?